# Running a command in power shell profile script has different behaviour than command line

Tags: powershell

then I run `cmd /c net use h: /d` from the powershell command line it all succeeds

but when I run the same command in the powershell $profile script it asks for a manual confirmation.

[image]

Anyone know how to prevent the confirmation please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cannot find a way to force the net program to force the drive deletion, however I can use the following powershell script to [control the Windows Script Host](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9bbdkx3k%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) to

[map a drive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kst88h6%28v=VS.85%29.aspx):

```
(New-Object -ComObject WScript.Network).MapNetworkDrive("H:", '\\SVNAS301\blah')
```

remove a mapping

```
(New-Object -ComObject WScript.Network).RemoveNetworkDrive("H:")
```

Or [remove a mapping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d16d7wbf%28VS.85%29.aspx) with force

```
(New-Object -ComObject WScript.Network).RemoveNetworkDrive("H:", 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(New-Object -ComObject WScript.Network).RemoveNetworkDrive("H:", 1, 1)
```

The second 1 at the end I believe is for bUpdateProfile. The drive would not disappear from the Explorer window unless that value was there.

Comment: Yeah, the syntax is `object.RemoveNetworkDrive(strName, [bForce], [bUpdateProfile])`, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d16d7wbf%28v=vs.84%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396